# Suffix corresponding to an idea described with two nouns

Tags: syntactic-analysis, suffixes

Please pardon my lack of understanding for major English Language concepts, I'll be using layman's terms.

Now, I've encountered this issue in the past while writing. Consider this text:

> That was about the best he could do, *information density wise*.

You can replace *information density* with loads of other ideas which must be described using two nouns, i.e., *refresh rate*, *focal length*, *cooking time*, etc.

The problem is, "wise" in that sentence was supposed to be used in its suffix form, and it too could be replaced with loads of other descriptive suffixes.

**How do I add a descriptive suffix to an idea described with two inseparable words?**

*Information density-wise?*
*Information-density-wise?*
*Information density -wise?*

Comment: Please let me know if there are any better tags I can add to this.

Comment: Should the last read: information-density wise? The first and last are the same othervise. I'd choolse the middle one, but would prefer a construction like, 'as far as information density/cooking time was concerned'.

Comment: @SConroy I think you misunderstand. I am trying to attach "-wise" to the idea "information density," not trying to concatenate two different ideas. As for the list of three, I meant to put a space there, though, don't ask me why as I'm just shooting in the dark. My thought process was something like: (information density)-wise.

Comment: "-wise," in its suffix form, forms adjectives. Think, clockwise. "Security-wise, there are a few problems."

Comment: Terminology-wise, that's not correct. The _-wise_ suffix forms contextual adverbs of manner and circumstance. That's why you can use  _-wise_ words at either end of a sentence, grammar-wise. That's how adverbs behave; adjectives are either predicates or else they modify some noun phrase; either way, their position in the sentence is fixed and not variable at will.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, you're saying there is no solution? I can't say "That was about the best he could do, information density wise?" Edit: Actually, I'm not really sure what you're saying. Google tells me that the suffix makes adjectives, which I thought made sense since I can say things like "The clockwise disc," right? Or can I not?

Comment: What's "a clockwise disc"? _Clockwise_ describes a direction of circular travel, as in _He walked clockwise around the building_; that's an adverb of motion. And I didn't say there's no solution. I have no idea what problem you need a solution to. If you want to say _information-density-wise_, go right ahead and say it. Though it's going to be hard to pronounce, because applying a lexical suffix to a phrase does strange things to the intonation and stress of the phrase when it's stuffed into a word jacket.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was thinking it sounded off as I wrote it, but I couldn't see why. Now, I get it. Clockwise would need to describe a verb, hence adverb. My problem as I see it with my limited scope of the right jargon is syntax based, I guess. I'm just looking for the right way to write this phrase, and phrases constructed similarly.

Comment: @JohnLawler Consider this: "Everything rotated the way it ought to, clock-wise." I'm looking to write a sentence with a similar structure. Consider: "The computer received the inputs all the same, information density wise." What seems ambiguous to me in this example sentence is the placement of the hyphen. It was obvious in the first sentence but not so much the second, where the idea which the suffix "-wise" is suffixing is two inseparable words constituting the whole idea.

Comment: When you're making up a new word, you get to put the punctuation wherever you think it should be. It's your language, after all.

Comment: Drop the hyphen: "densitywise" is fine, just as "clockwise", "lengthwise" etc., are.

Comment: @BillJ Okay, so you mean to say that "information densitywise" is a viable method?

Comment: @JohnLawler That seems a bit of an odd concept to me. Aren't there approved ways to place the punctuation? Standards and whatnot?

Comment: [Many standards](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf). All different. And changing constantly. Take your pick, or make your own. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think I understand now. This would seem to answer my question.